# Editing the variable PATH

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, path

I want to start script just by typing `script` not the full path of the script for example `~/Desktop/name/script` so i tried to edit variable `PATH`

```
PATH="$PATH:~/Desktop/name"
```

in the name folder i have a script called "script". When i want to run script just by typing script it says  `Script started, file is typescript` and create an empty `typescript` file in my pwd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the program `script` is already installed, check `whereis script` for its location and `man script` for what it does.

There are several possibilities to make your program work as you intended:

1. Simply by changing the name form `script` to a unique program name not used yet. The simplest method, which will also make sure that you do not "deactivate" some programs (for your shell environment).
2. The `PATH` variable is read front to end. So if there are two `script` executables to be found the first match will be taken. You can change your path as `PATH="~/Desktop/name:$PATH"` so your `script` will be the first hit. The original `script` would then always have to be executed by an absolute path e.g. `/usr/local/bin/script`
3. You could introduce an alias for script like (bash syntax) `alias script='/home/user/Desktop/name/script'`. Besides the absolute path for executing the original `script` program, an alias can also be escaped by `\script` to match the original non-alias behaviour.